# An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host - Google Actions SDK (gactions)

Tags: actions-on-google

We are trying to update our google action using actions SDK by executing the below command in CLI.

**Command:**

`gactions update --action_package GoogleAssistantAction.json --project PROJECTNAMEHERE`

Below is the error message we're getting

**Error message:**

```
Error: Get https://dl.google.com/gactions/updates.json: read tcp 172.30.63.145:1430->172.217.13.238:443: wsarecv: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
Pushing the app for the Assistant for testing...
POST /v2/users/me/previews/PROJECT NAME HERE:batchUpdatePreviewFromAgentDraft HTTP/1.1
Host: actions.googleapis.com
User-Agent: Gactions-CLI/2.1.3 (windows; amd64; stable/dff629ae63fd0b047d19687b79274524569714e6)
Content-Length: 540
Content-Type: application/json
Accept-Encoding: gzip
```

However, based on our research and troubleshooting, we figured out that the issue stems from `gactions` not being proxy-aware. All internet traffic should be going through bluecoat proxy, where it will then be passed through the firewall. However, our internet traffic (port 443) is directly reaching out to the internet, which is causing it to be blocked by the firewall. Can anyone please help figuring the proxy settings in our application so that it won’t directly reach the internet? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

At present, gactions only supports transparent proxy configurations. That is, proxy configurations that processes don't need to be explicitly be aware of.

Unfortunately, I'm unable to give you specific guidance for bluecoat. If you're able configure it as a transparent proxy, gactions should work in your environment.